# Connecting two separate databases to the desktop version and on server in Power BI

Tags: server, powerbi, database-connection, desktop-application

I need to connect to the Developer database in my desktop verison and after publishing i need to connect to the dashboard to the live data base.Is there a way to do this.Normal practice is we connect to the same data base in desktop version and in server.But i need to use two databases in the server and the desktop version.

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be best to control the database connection with a parameter of the database name/settings, then use that parameter in the connection. A good outline is [here](https://jlsql.blog/2019/01/16/power-bi-parameters-data-sources/).

[image]

Before deploying change the parameter name from the dev to the live database, then publish.

What Power BI cannot do is publish the report without overwriting the dataset and connections. So for example in your requirement, you want your desktop to point at dev and your live to point at live. You can do this, but by only changing the details before publishing. You can change the data source connection after deployment using the power bi api and some powershell.

Comment: Parameter values can also be changed in dataset's settings page in Power BI service, so no need to use the API unless you try to automate it.